# React+materialUi Навигация на элементах Tab+Link

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Здравствуйте я новичок в frontend разработке.
Хочу сделать панель навигации используя `Tabs`,
чтобы при переходе на `Tab` срабатывал `Link` или `NavLink` для перехода по соответствующему `Route`.

пример стилизации `Tab` вкладок materialUi https://codesandbox.io/s/cvn6w

Я не до конца понял этот пример, что меня не устраивает в примере, я хотел отдельным компонентом Nav отрисовать `Tabs` с переходами по ссылкам `Link`, чтобы Route уже отработал.

```
import React, { Suspense, lazy } from "react";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import Nav from "./components/Nav";

const DeviceOption = lazy(() =>  import("./components/deviceOptionComponents/DeviceOption"));
const About = lazy(() => import("./components/About"));

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CssBaseline />
      <Router>
        <React.Fragment>
          <Nav />
          <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={DeviceOption} />
              <Route path="/about" component={About} />
              <Route children={() => <h2>Not Found</h2>} />
            </Switch>
          </Suspense>
        </React.Fragment>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Панель навигации хочу отрисовать в компоненте `Nav`.

Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос через использование Redirect

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import AppBar from "@material-ui/core/AppBar";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import Tab from "@material-ui/core/Tab";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

function TabPanel(props) {
  const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;

  return (
    <Typography
      component="div"
      role="tabpanel"
      hidden={value !== index}
      id={`simple-tabpanel-${index}`}
      aria-labelledby={`simple-tab-${index}`}
      {...other}
    >
      {value === index && <Box p={3}>{children}</Box>}
    </Typography>
  );
}

TabPanel.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node,
  index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,
  value: PropTypes.any.isRequired
};

function a11yProps(index) {
  return {
    id: `simple-tab-${index}`,
    "aria-controls": `simple-tabpanel-${index}`
  };
}

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper
  }
}));

export default function Nav2() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

  const handleChange = (e, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  function RedirectRender(param) {
    switch (param) {
      case 0:
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
      case 1:
        return <Redirect to="/About" />;
      case 2:
        return <Redirect to="/NotFound" />;
      default:
        return <Redirect to="/About" />;
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          aria-label="simple tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab label="Item Two" {...a11yProps(1)} />
          <Tab label="Item Three" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      {RedirectRender(value)}
    </div>
  );
}
```